# Exploded EAR deployment fails on Weblogic 10.3.4

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I've been trying to get my exploded EAR deployed/started on Weblogic through the Admin Console but it fails with this error:

```
BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating start task for application 'xyz'.> 
####<Sep 1, 2013 4:10:51 AM CDT> <Warning> <Deployer>  <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1378026651456> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1510)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate    
...
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
    Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:626)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
 ....
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
```

I'm not able to figure out the cause of the issue with these logs.

The exploded EAR has this folder structure:
1) lib directory - consisting of jars
2) META-INF directory - consisting of application.xml, weblogic-application.xml 
3) war directory - has jsps, WEB-INF folder (has weblogic.xml)

Let me know if you need more details. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue myself. Here are the details, in case anyone is interested:

I modified the weblogic-application.xml (present under my application EAR>META-INF folder) to include org.hibernate.* and javax.persistence.* packages. Restarted the servers and redeployed the EAR (exploded). I don't see the errors anymore and the deployment was successful.

```
 .....
<prefer-application-packages>
     ......
            <package-name>org.hibernate.*</package-name>
            <package-name>javax.persistence.*</package-name>
        </prefer-application-packages>

    .......
```